# Notifications from SQLServer to Java

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, spring, notifications

I want to implement notifications in Java Spring. How to get the notifications to Java on change in database/table ? Database used is SQLServer 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Triggers on specified tables writes queue of changes and **your** process is polling this table
- TimeStamp columns on specified tables and checking of @@DBCC value
- Use your own CLR trigger which knows how to interact with your app proactively
- In Sql Server 2005 you may use Notification Services, which are not available in 2008+

Comment: Thanks Dok, but I dont want to poll from java. I want the mod info from db to java.

Comment: any alternate for notification services in 2008+

Comment: No, you may use only mentioned above